# What is the best way to learn android quickly

Tags: android

actually I am on 6 months internship program in a company and I am told to make an application in android with no help provided by the company and I have never done android before , so can you suggest me any faster way of learning android . Please let me know if there is .

Comment: http://www.apress.com/9781430224198  THIS BOOK by Mark Murphy.

Comment: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: Please don't give negative points

Comment: Do you have 6 months to make the app? Or will they evaluate it and tell you how to improve on it etc? Cause it kinda sounds like.. sit there, do something and leave us be. If this is the case. Bring them lots of coffee for a good evaluation.

Comment: @alextsc I thought this site is for help .

Comment: @TRonZ It is, but not for every question out there, there are some rules to consider. Read the FAQ to get an idea what's appropriate here. Otherwise you will be question banned pretty fast given your other questions are also low-quality for SO standards and have gathered downvotes too. It's a two sided-deal: You do us a favor by asking a quality question and we do you a favor by helping you. Or your don't do that and we don't answer. Nobody is obliged to help you or upvote you in the end.

Comment: @TRonZ Hehe, remember me? :p

I also started with android as interhsip, without any help.
Also for 6 months (done at 22 june).

But first setup Eclipse with the SDK and start with the Hello world tutorial (can be found, just use google). You can find ALOT on the internet. If you know what project to make, start with little steps! Just program a piece of it, test it and when it works, proceed to next "Function"

Also Very usefull to make a plan where you discribe all functions, that need to be in the app first

Comment: To get started with android quickly just visit   developandroidapp.com/?p=21  link

Answer (score 5):

Try to go through the basics.

Visit these links which are helpful to beginners

- [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- [Android Training](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/introducing-android-training.html)
- [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html)
- and obviously, you have [GOOGLE](http://www.google.com) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Hope it helps !!!

### EDIT

For Android Development on [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html)

Links for specific topic is also available.

- [List View](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview)
- [SQLite Database](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) etc...

Comment: +1 for Vogella, always good stuff there

Comment: @Gama why Stack Overflow is the last link :P

Comment: You can virtually get solution/idea/suggestion to any of your doubts here !

Answer (score 1):

You can start by making [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) your start page.

Secondly, try to complete some tutorials [like this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/introduction-to-android-development/) and start building your own application once you are done with basic tutorials.

Comment: I've done exactly what you are about to do TRonZ, and starting at the developer page works. Just download eclipse and do some tutorials to get the hang of it. I also recommend to read up on the activity and service lifecycles and functions. Those are the most important things to understand about android.

Answer (score 0):

Hey TRonz me too has been trapped exactly like you.First of all you have go-through and practice this [demo](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.in/2010/01/hello-world-your-first-android.html)

Eclipse ide is the best ide to work with android and it will support all type of plug-ins in the form of just installing.Which ide are you using? if other ide's just turn to eclipse[eclipse-jee-indigo].It will makes you flexible coding and etc.,

If you really need some soft-copies guide about android just go to amazon.com and do download appropriate demands(cost-free).

Gud luk!..

Comment: thanks man and I'm already using Eclipse